# Вставить пустую строку в отчет на СКД

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, уважаемые гуру.

Написал отчет на СКД, все вроде хорошо, но тут заказчик говорит, что нужно вставить еще строку в статьи, в которой будет расчитываться НДС. Пробовал в предопределенных макетах манипулировать с полями, но у меня получается, что для каждой статьи выводится дополнительное поле, а нужно всего два (одно в платежах, одно в поступлениях). Вопрос: можно ли в системе компоновки данных вставлять произвольные строки в группировки, если можно, то как? Есть ли способ это сделать средствами языка 1С?   Стрелками отмечены места, куда нужно вставлять строки

[image]

**UPD** Проблема решается с помощью использования набора данных - "объект". Источником данных которого является таблица значений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается с помощью использования набора данных - "объект". Источником данных которого является таблица значений.